# Between query doesn't seem to work well

Tags: c#

This doesn't seem to work well any help

```
this.con.Open();
string selectCommandText = "Select * from paymentrecord where Payment_date >= " + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " and  Payment_date <" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new     OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommandText, this.con);
OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dataTable);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
this.con.Close();
```

this one also doesn't seem to work well. it gives me records from different dates, sometimes too i don't get any records while they are records with the date i selected

```
this.con.Open();
        string selectCommandText = "Select * from paymentrecord where Payment_date  BETWEEN " + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") +" and "+ dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "";
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommandText, this.con);
        OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
        this.con.Close();
```

Comment: Format your code and explain the problem.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Use parametrized queries and you will get safety and the expected results. Two for the price of one

Comment: use parameterized queries, you fix is to put ' on dates like where Payment_date  BETWEEN '" + ..." + '"

Comment: @brykneval there is even more to fix: date formatting is also wrong => see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39406/5 - parameters will solve all problems here

Answer (score -3):

Did your query give u the correct result?

I think Payment_date is a string. String comparison doesn't give u correct result. It should be DateTime instead.

The operator greater than or lesser than will compare the values of the paymentDate in string. So it gives u wierd result.

Comment: It would be also more helpful if you only post something in the "answer" section if you have an answer to the question

Comment: @viresh it gives me records from different dates somethings no records appear

Comment: I have less than 50 rep, I will modifying my post later :)

Comment: Posting comments as answers only increases the time until you are able to comment.